# Will using ntpd possibly mess up cron jobs?

Tags: unix, cron, ntp

My system has a lot of time drift, after a couple of week it can be ahead by around 5 minutes.

To fix this, I installed ntp, which can help fix drift and of course sync the time to the ntp servers occasionally.

Suppose I have a cron job for something like backing up files. Is the following scenario possible?

```
02:00:00 - Cron starts a job
02:00:03 - Ntpd syncs time back 5 seconds to 01:59:58
02:00:00 - 2:00 gets repeated and cron job runs twice
```

If the cron job copies large files, the second run might try overwriting files the first job is not finished writing to.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what the `cron(8)` man page says (this is for Vixie cron; other implementations might behave differently):

> Special considerations exist when the clock is changed by less than 3
>   hours, for example at the beginning and end of day‐ light savings
>   time. If the time has moved forwards, those jobs which would have run
>   in the time that was skipped will  be run  soon  after the change.
>   Conversely, if the time has moved backwards by less than 3 hours,
>   those jobs that fall into the repeated time will not be re-run.
>
> Only jobs that run at a particular time (not specified as @hourly, nor
>   with '*' in the  hour  or  minute  specifier)  are affected. Jobs
>   which are specified with wildcards are run based on the new time
>   immediately.
>
> Clock changes of more than 3 hours are considered to be corrections to
>   the clock, and the new time is used immediately.

Comment: So, the answer is "yes, your scenario can happen", right?

Comment: @BenjaminW. My reading is that OP's scenario may or may not occur. If the cron job specifies 2:00:00 explicitly, then if ntpd sets the clock back 5 secs, the job does NOT get repeated. But if the job specifies wild cards (like run every hour), then it WILL get repeated. But I'm just interpreting the docs quoted by Keith.

Answer (score 1):

In this particular scenario it might but I would suggest that you put a locking mechanism into the backup job that it will only allows it to run once:

In PERL you can do the following:

```
flock("/tmp/backup-running", LOCK_EX) || die "I'm already running";
```

While shell may not provide you a similar mechanism except by running:

```
touch /tmp/backup-running
if [ -f "/tmp/backup-running" ]
then
    exit 0;
fi

....


/bin/rm /tmp/backup-running
```

which is prone to problems other languages provide you with similar facilities as PERL.

Answer (score 0):

ntp.conf allows you to control how often ntp connects to the time server to make corrections. The minimum is 64 seconds by default (minpoll) and the default for maxpoll is 1024 seconds.  see man ntp.conf

Therefore, if you correct time manually at a time when it will not impact things, then start ntp, the amount of drift is going to be small, very much subsecond changes.

One of our m4000's has a clock like that, and we never have had a problem.

Note: The only problem with a lock file is that if the backup severely abends no more backups will run until the lock file is reset.